# How to take a photo in Android, using full image size(not thumbnail) and compress the image to bytes?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, photo, image-compression

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong maybe I'm not using the image at all or I'm compressing the image in the wrong way because when I'm trying to send it to a server it responds me saying that the size is over 10 MB when my phone takes pictures jpg around 7-9 MB (In the Edit.java I have a comment that I before was using the thumbnail but needed to change it cause the thumbnail has a bad quality when I try to see it in a Desktop)

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>

<provider
            android:authorities="cam.com.example.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_path"/>
        </provider>
```

file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="/"/>
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/"/>
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="/"/>
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="/"/>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="/"/>

</paths>
```

Edit.java

```
btn_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                        File imageFile = null;
                        try{
                            imageFile=getImageFile();
                        }catch (IOException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(imageFile!=null){
                            Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Edit.this,"cam.com.example.fileprovider",imageFile);
                            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toasty.warning(getApplicationContext(), IC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

                }
            }

        });



public File getImageFile() throws IOException{
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageName = "jpg_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName,".jpg",storageDir);
        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (imagenString == null) {

                File imgFile = new File(currentImagePath);
                String path = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                imagenString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

/* **Before I was doing this, but the thumbnail has such a bad quality so needed to change it**

                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                imagenString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);*/
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're converting your image to Base64-encoding string which makes the size of the data bigger.

In the following code you're using a value of 100 for the compression, 100 is least compression and high quality.

```
mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
```

You can try to compress more your image, but it reduces the quality a bit:

```
mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are taking a picture with the user's choice of camera app. Usually, that will be saved as a JPEG image. JPEG images are compressed image formats, optimized for "real-world" images like photos.

You then attempt to read it all into memory. This is not a good plan, as you may not have enough memory to do that, for a full-size photo.

You then attempt to take the resulting `Bitmap` and encode it in PNG. PNG is a compressed image format, but one that is designed for icons and other artwork. A photo will almost always take more space in PNG than in JPEG. Worse, you are trying to encode it as a PNG into memory — again, you may not have sufficient memory to do this.

You then attempt to convert the encoded PNG into base-64. This will take up even more space than the encoded PNG, and, once again, you may not have sufficient memory for this.

I would expect your app to crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` a lot.

The best solution is to get rid of most of this, and simply upload the JPEG direct from disk. Do not load it into memory, do not convert it to PNG, and do not convert it to base-64.